# Control Array serialization without a collection class

Tags: c#, serialization

I have this code:

```
public static void Main()
        {
            var test = new TestXML[] {new TestXML() {TestAttribute = "blah"}};

            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("abc", "a/b/c/d/e/f/g");


            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestXML[]));

            var sw = new StringWriter();
            var xw = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, settings);

            serializer.Serialize(xw,test,ns);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Continued...

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "a/b/c/d/e/f/g",IncludeInSchema = true)]
    public class TestXML
    {
        public string TestAttribute { get; set; }   
    }
```

The code outputs:

```
 <ArrayOfTestXML
 xmlns:abc="a/b/c/d/e/f/g"><TestXML><abc:TestAttribute>blah</abc:TestAttribute></TestXML></ArrayOfTestXML>
```

We have a 3rd party dependency that limits our ability to add a collection class to the serialization process.  Is it possible to control serialization so that `<TestXML>` gets the prefix, abc?

Answer (score 0):

What about not to use standard XmlSerializer (which is good for cases where XML itself not have much constraints and used just for serialize/deserialize) and write own Serialization support for your classes?